# How can i count rows by two groups according to time filter?

Tags: sas

I'm trying to count my product sales for each customers according to their transaction time. To illustrate, a customer has three types of product such as computer, printer and keyboard and I want to put a counter showing the order of that sale in the last 12 months if this item is not flagged as 1 (I also have a flag if it is sold with campaign or not). Here is how my data looks like;

```
ID  PRODUCT   SALETIME CAMPAIGN_FLAG
100 Keyboard    201705             0
100 printer     201708             1
100 computer    201801             0
100 keyboard    201806             0
200 printer     201801             1
200 keyboard    201805             0 
200 computer    201808             0
```

What I would like to get;

```
ID  PRODUCT  SALETIME CAMPAIGN_FLAG COUNT
100 Keyboard   201705             0     1
100 printer    201708             1     1
100 computer   201801             0     2
100 keyboard   201806             0     2
200 printer    201801             1     0
200 keyboard   201805             0     1
200 computer   201808             0     2
```

I have tried many things like left joining the table with the same table with only sales having campaing=0 flag (I brought only the SALETIME column to the right) . Then tried adding a column for 1 year previous of saletime and putting a flag if the sale is between 1 year before and now, named Count_sum. Then i took sum of Count_sum grouped by id, product, SALETIME. This actually worked but i couldn't handle if a customer has two products in the same month, in this case i lose the counter. For example:

```
ID  PRODUCT  SALETIME CAMPAIGN_FLAG COUNT
100 Keyboard   201705             0     1
100 printer    201708             1     1
100 computer   201801             0     3
100 keyboard   201801             0     3
200 printer    201801             1     0
200 keyboard   201805             0     2
200 computer   201805             0     2
```

I couldn't figure out how to fix this. I will be thankful if you could help.

Comment: Can you include some of the 'many things' you've tried? Please refer to the guidelines on how to ask a question here [ask].

Comment: You need to expand on what your criteria is for determining your 'want' data set. The logic on how to go from one table to another is not clear. Why does ID200 with printer start at 0? Is Keyboard different than 'keyboard' (case is different) or does that even matter?

Answer (score 0):

You would essentially group by SALETIME and ID, e.g.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM TABLE GROUP BY ID, SALETIME ORDER BY ID
```

However, the result would not be exactly the same, since I can't work out the criteria just by looking at your data ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If I  understood you well,  what you are looking is to within each id you want to number only for first instance of particular product.

please not you have Keyboard and keyboard in your datalines or in your data this can cause problems if you have data in same form and you need to make it in single value as keyboard or Keyboard not both

first create dataset

```
  data have;
 input ID  PRODUCT $   SALETIME CAMPAIGN_FLAG;
 datalines;
100 keyboard    201705             0
100 printer     201708             1
100 computer    201801             0
100 keyboard    201806             0
200 printer     201801             1
200 keyboard    201805             0 
200 computer    201808             0
;
```

Then sort data by id and product, this is to use logic in next steps, so that you do not count for same product again within same id.

```
 proc sort data=have out=have1 ;
 by id  product;
 run;


   data have2;
    set have1 ;
   by id product;
  if first.product then num = 0;
  else num=1;
  run;
```

/* then sort it back in the data as it is by using id with saletime*/

```
proc sort data=have2 out=have3;
 by id SALETIME;
   run;
```

finally apply the logic

```
 data want(drop =num);
  set have3;
  by id;
  if first.id then count=0;
  if CAMPAIGN_FLAG = 0 and num = 0
   then count+1;
  run;
```

proc print data=want;
    run;

[image]